# How to assert on the text in a DatePicker which has the compact style?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I am rendering a [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) in my application with the [compact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle/compact) style as follows:

```
DatePicker("Date Selected", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
    .accessibilityIdentifier("DatePicker")
    .datePickerStyle(.compact)
```

I am able to tap on the [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) in a UI test, select the date that I want in the calendar-style popup, and then dismiss the popup as follows:

```
// 1. Show the DatePicker popup
application.datePickers["DatePicker"].tap()
        
// 2. Choose a date in the popup
application.datePickers.collectionViews.buttons["Friday, January 14"].tap()
        
// 3. Dismiss the DatePicker popup
application.datePickers["DatePicker"].tap()
```

(All of the above is demonstrated in [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUI-experiments/tree/master/App5) sample application.)

Is it possible to assert that the [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) is now showing the date that I selected? If so, how?

Comment: Why verifying `selectedDate` is not enough for you?

Comment: This is for a UI test running in an Xcode UI Testing Bundle. I want to verify that the text displayed in the DatePicker when my view is loaded under certain conditions is the text that I expect. If there is a better way to test this in the context of a UI test, I am open to it. Note that in a UI Testing Bundle the test process runs in a separate process to the application under test and is not permitted to access memory or storage belonging to the application under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first button in the DatePicker, as follows:

```swift
let label = application.datePickers["DatePicker"].buttons.firstMatch.value as? String
XCTAssertEqual(label, "Jan 14, 2022")
```

If you look at the element hierarchy, something like this is shown (output taken from one of my tests):

```
Element subtree:
  →DatePicker, 0x106605ab0, {{244.3, 258.3}, {116.7, 34.3}}, identifier: '@#datePicker1'
    Button, 0x106605bd0, {{244.3, 258.3}, {116.7, 34.3}}, label: 'Date Picker', value: Sep 5, 2023
```

There is a Button with the selected data in its value property.

(Tested using Xcode 15, iOS 17, SwiftUI)

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Annett Schwarze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642526/1071320) and taking into account that the `Button` in the `DatePicker` has a `label` value of `'Date Picker'`, you can match on the `Button` by means of its label, as follows:

```swift
let datePickerButton = application.datePickers["DatePicker"].buttons["Date Picker"]
```

You can then assert on the `Button`'s text value as follows:

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(datePickerButton.value as? String, "25 Nov 2022")
```

You can see an example of this in the `test_date_picker()` function in [this class](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUI-experiments/blob/master/App5/App5UITests/App5UITests.swift).